# How to create a regex that matches alpha chars up to, but not including, whitespace?

Tags: c++, regex

With this input:

```
"hello the3re world"
```

I'm trying to create a regex that will match words containing just alpha characters and not digits.

I'm using std::regex_search with flag std::regex_constants::match_continuous.
With this regex `[[:alpha:]]+` the first call to regex_search will give me back "hello". If I then advance over "hello" and any white space and try again with "the3re world", I get back: "the".

But, what I really want at this point is a failure to match as the "3" shouldn't be valid in a word.

Comment: Can't you use a custom character class of, say, Latin letters: `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b`? Are you using Visual Studio? Please post your code.

Comment: Also.. you need to use word boundaries.... with your regex it should be `\b[[:alpha:]]+\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adding my comment as an answer) You should use word boundaries `\b` for this purpose..

```
\b[[:alpha:]]+\b  //or "\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b" as per the syntax..
```

Comment: Yes, it works with `\\b`s. Tested. :) A plus from me for reminding about ECMAScript syntax http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
string line1 = "hello the3re world";
string regexStr1 = "\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b";
regex rg1(regexStr1); 
smatch sm1;
while (regex_search(line1, sm1, rg1)) {
        std::cout << sm1[0] << std::endl;
        line1 = sm1.suffix().str();
}
```

Output:

[image]